# How to open cmd and pass parameter through batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file to run the command. I want to add IP in my command.

My command is

```
 route add 26.284.254.269 mask 245.245.256.236 24.18.16.4
```

The above IPs are examples not actual.

I have created a batch file named **runAs.bat**. It successfully run in login Administrator.
I need to open command prompt as runas domain-name\administrator password and pass the above command in it in windows xp.
I have used the following command.

```
runas domain-name\administrator password cmd "route add 26.284.254.269 mask 245.245.256.236 24.18.16.4"
```

But it shows RUNAS USAGE:
How to use RUNAS.

Where is the problem in my command. I had google about it but noone could help me. Please give some suggestion or batchfile command for this.

Comment: Could you not put the command inside the batch file rather than passing it as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The runas command usage shows that the user must be prefixed with a forward slash; possibly that is why you are getting the message. From the runas /? help:

```
RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/netonly] ]
        /user:<UserName> program
```

You can execute a command with cmd by using

```
cmd /c [command]
```

Comment: hm, any idea why this is not working?

runas.exe /user:Administrator "cmd /c explorer"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> runas /user:domain-name\administrator "cmd /c route add 26.284.254.269 mask 245.245.256.236 24.18.16.4"

runas command does not have password parameter - it will be really insecure to add admin password to batch file.
But you can use /savecred parameter.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how can I specify domain name here because I have 50 systems and I have login there as local admin. so how can I specify there as domain name and I used computername\administrator here ex. runas /user:QCAS\administrator "cmd /c route add 26.284.254.269 mask 245.245.256.236 24.18.16.4".  But it shows runas usage. I have put my administrator password after username but it also shows the error. Error is The system cannot find the path specified. Please let me know where I am doing wrong?